# How to make the player move constantly and also move to fixed position smoothly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I want the player to constantly move into the z direction but also want to combine this with the option to move the player to one of 3 fixed x positions (either -1.5, 0 or 1.5) in a smooth transition like in the Vector3.Leap function. I tried several options which all didn't work.

Does anybody know how I would have to do this?

Comment: If you made attempts before, it can be helpful for you to share them and then indicate how they didn't achieve your goals. This can more clearly show your intended behaviour and how you've already approached the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Split the two and move constantly on the Z axis but interpolate on the X axis:

```csharp
[SerializeField] private float zVelocity = 1f;
[SerializeField] private float smoothTime = 0.3f;

private float xVelocity = 0f;
private float targetX = 0f;

public void SetTargetX(float newTargetX)
{
    targetX = newTargetX;
}

public void SetZVelocity(float newZVelocity)
{
    zVelocity = newZVelocity;
}

private void Update ()
{
    var position = transform.position;
    position.z += zVelocity * Time.deltaTime;
    position.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(position.x, targetX, ref xVelocity, smoothTime);
    transform.position = position;
}
```